# Another user signed in using spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a web application using Spring 3.

Suppose I opened the login page in two tabs. In one tab I sign in using one user (admin) and then click on add user menu (it will show the form with create button). Then in the other tab, I log in using another user (primary user which does not have add user menu).

After going back to the previous logged page and hit the create button, it is throwing error since the session has been overridden with the new user logged in and the menu buttons changed for this user.

I am using the following code for session management:

```
<security:session-management session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" />
```

What I want is if I click create button I want show the message that "another user signed in from the same browser. leave this page" or it will redirect to the home page of the new user.

Comment: Please can you post the error? Is it related to invalid session or access denied error?

Comment: @Javakid I just want to redirect to the new logged user home page, I don't bother about the error as I want to redirect to new logged in user home page

Answer (score 0):

If it is a custom/generic exception, you may use the below configuration to globally catch the exception and redirect to home page

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
          <prop key="com.xyz.SomeException">homePage</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```